# Backbone.js fetch error in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, internet-explorer-7

**The setup**

Backbone.js for MV* on frontend, RequireJS for dependency management, and REST services to retrieve data from DB.  The services are on the same domain as the web app.

**The problem**

When I fetch a collection from the server via a REST service in IE 7, the error callback is thrown.  When I check the xhr object, the status is 0 and the statusText is 0.  This is only an issue in IE 7.  FF and Chrome have no problem with the ajax GET.

**Here is the code (AMD definition)**

```
define([
  'underscore', 
  'backbone', 
  'models/imageLink',
  'app/registry'
  ], function(_, Backbone, ImageLink, AppReg) {

    var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({


        ajaxRequest: false,

        highestKey: 0,

        polling : false,

        pollDelay: 7500,


        // Reference to this collection's model.
        model: ImageLink,


        url: function(){ 

            return "http://samedomain:4020/api/imageLinks" + "?userId=" + this.user;
        },

        user: "",

        initialize: function() {

            // ensure correct context of 'this'
            _.bindAll(this, 'startPolling', 'stopPolling', 'executePolling', "onFetch");

            var _this=this;

            console.log('Image Links collection has been initialized.');


        },

        // used for sorting collection, sorts based on the lowercase value of the imageLink's text attribute
        comparator: function(imageLink) { 

            return imageLink.get('text').toLowerCase(); 

        },

        // override parse function to prevent backbone from updating empty data returned from server
        parse: function(response,options) {

            //debugger;

            if (options.xhr.status===204) {
                return this.toJSON();
            }
            else
                return response;

        },

        getHighestKey: function() {

            if (this.length) {
                return this.at(this.length-1).get("id");
            }
            else {  
                return this.highestKey;
            }

        },

        startPolling : function() {

            this.polling = true;

            this.highestKey = this.getHighestKey();

            this.executePolling();

        },

        stopPolling : function() {

            this.polling = false;

        },

        executePolling : function() {

            if (this.ajaxRequest == "") {

                this.ajaxRequest = this.fetch({ reset:true, complete: this.onFetch, timeout: 30000, data: $.param({ key: this.highestKey }), 
                    error: function(model, xhr, options) {
                                   alert("Error\n"+xhr.readyState+"\n"+xhr.status+"\n"+xhr.statusText.toString()+"\n"+xhr.responseText);

                        }
                });
            }

        },

        onFetch : function () {

            this.ajaxRequest = "";

            this.highestKey = this.getHighestKey();

            if( this.polling ) {

                // poll database
                setTimeout(this.executePolling,this.pollDelay);
            }

        }


    });

    return collection;

});
```

**Note**

The page works fine when rendering under IE 7 using the developer tool in IE 9.  The problem only occurs when loaded in IE 7 stand alone.

Also, I perform the following at app start up:

```
      // do not cache any ajax requests
      $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

      // needed for IE CORS support
      $.support.cors = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I am hosting the service on a different port than 80, where my javascript is running.  So, I was running into IE7's lack of CORS support, even with the same domains, the port numbers have to match too.